# The server could not find the requested resource when generating Kubernetes Persistent Volume

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I use minikube on windows 10 and try to generate Persistent Volume with minikube dashboard. Belows are my PV yaml file contents.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume 
metadata:
  name: blog-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: blog-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  volumeName: blog-pv
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 500Mi
```

But minikube dashboard throw the following errors.

```
## Deploying file has failed
the server could not find the requested resource
```

But I can generate PV with kubectl command as executing the following command

```
kubectl apply -f pod-pvc-test.yaml
```

For your information, the version of kubectl.exe is

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.2", GitCommit:"59603c6e503c87169aea6106f57b9f242f64df89", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-18T23:22:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

How can I generate the Persistent Volume with minikube dashboard as well as kubectl command?

**== Updated Part==**

```
> kubectl get pv
NAME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
blog-pv   1Gi        RWO            Recycle          Bound    default/blog-pv-claim   manual                  5m1s
```

Answer (score 1):

First, apply the resource one by one. So make sure this problem can be isolated to PV(PersistentVolume) or PVC (PersistentVolumeClaim)

Second, please adjust the hostPath to others, `/mnt/data` normally is a mounted or NFS  folder, maybe that's the issue, you can adjust to some other real path for testing.

After you applied them, please show the output

```
kubectl get pv,pvc
```

You should be fine to know the root cause now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried one by one and found the 'kind:PersistentVolume' threw the errors only with minikube dashboard. After executing 'kind:PersistentVolume' with kubectl.exe command, the rest of resources are generated successfully on minukube dashboard.

Comment: did you change the hostPath and apply again, any different error?

Comment: As you mentioned, I set the hostPath path to "/tmp". But I am afraid the same error occurs. And I also use the kubectl.exe command, then this time it works without error.

Comment: will this be helpful? https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5569 . Seems you need upgrade `kubectl`

Comment: I am struggling to prove your reply. Kindly wait for couple of days.

Comment: It fails. I reinstall the minikube and kubectl with the new versions. But it throws "the server could not find the requested resource" error messages still. And with kubectl cli command PV is generated successfully. For your information I attach the "kubectl get pv" command output in updated part.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to reproduce the issue you've been describing on my minikube with the `v2.0.0-beta8` dashboard.

```
$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.9.1

$ kubectl version
Client Version: GitVersion:"v1.17.4"
Server Version: GitVersion:"v1.18.0"
```

Please note that the [offical guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/) reffers to `v2.0.0-beta8` which is broken :).

Recently there were [some fixes](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/4999) for the broken functionality (they'd been merged to `master` branch).

Please **update the version of the dashboard** to at least the `v2.0.0-rc6`.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0-rc6/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

I was able successfully creating PV and PVC (via dashboard) from yaml provided.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Joseph-hwang , just curious if you've fixed it.